# Android returning focus after something else is focused

Tags: android, focus, keyevent

I have problem with focusing.
I do some web stuff if focus is gain on edittext.

```
        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            if (b){
                //Web request
            }

        }
    });
```

On the other hand I have a KeyListener if enter is pressed (same EditText).

```
        editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (keyEvent.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                button.performClick();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

That certain button does something and focuses another EditText.
After that focus somehow comes back to to first edittext and Web request is called again.

So my question is how to Override onKey that focus is not gained back?
Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: remove focus from that view

Comment: please add this two properties to your main view in layout
**android:focusable="true"** and 
    **android:focusableInTouchMode="true"**